# I am trying to run file program, I get error FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, java-io

```
import java.io.*;  
class C{  
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
      FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("C.java");  
      FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("M.java");  
      int i=0;  
      while((i=fin.read())!=-1){  
        fout.write((byte)i);  
      }  
      fin.close();  
   }  
}
```

I try create file to read and write from where the code will be stored. In my case it was stored in C drive  (my program thats I created it there only     read and write file).

My program builds successfully but no output 
   application name - javaprogram 
package name- pack

Inside package I have placed two files `c.txt` and `m.txt`
I even want to know how is that we have `.java` file (I was trying with `c.txt` and `m.txt` rather than `.java`)

This IS WHAT I GET ERROR

```
init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\build\classes
compile-single:
run-single:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at javaapplication1.C.main(C.java:20)
```

Comment: What about looking up [FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)?

Comment: Does the file you are trying to read exist?

Comment: yes  exist in inside the same package .

Comment: I know i have gone wrong in pacing the file or path , but i want to know where exactly i need to place the  file     @stefan

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below you are missing something  file object

```
class C {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        File f1 = new File("C.java");
        File f2 = new File("M.java");

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read()) > 0)
        {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} 
}
```

Another elegant way of doing that is 
download Commons IO from this [Link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) and add it to your project library then use the code below.

```
class C {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        File f1 = new File("C.java");
        File f2 = new File("M.java");

        FileUtils.copyFile(f1, f2);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} }
```